# CSS3 & jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a loading circle that uses CSS3 Animations. So far I have coded some jQuery that shows a div container once the loading circle animation has finished. Is it possible to code the jQuery in entirely CSS?. Any help is much appreciated.

CSS:

```
/*Loading Circle*/

.x {
   height: 15px; 
   width: 15px; 
   background: #dedede; 
   border-radius: 50px; 
   display: inline-block;
}


.a {animation: fade 1s forwards;}
.b {animation: fade 2s forwards;}
.c {animation: fade 3s forwards;}


@keyframes fade {
0%   {opacity:0;}
50%  {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity:0;}}





/*Empty Container*/

.container {
   display:none; 
   background: #dedede;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;

}
```

JS:

```
function setup() {
  var e = document.getElementById("lastDot");
    e.addEventListener("animationend", function(){$("#mydiv").show();}, false);
}

setup()
```

HTML:

```
<div class="a x"></div>
<div class="b x"></div>
<div class="c x" id="lastDot"></div>

<div class="container" id="mydiv"></div>​
```

​
[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/vJsTr/6/)

Comment: Is the loading circle actually doing anything worth while (like telling the user that the page and/or additional content is loading) or is it for asthetics?

Comment: Then yeah sure, you would use the CSS3 timings.  Could you put what you already have on jsfiddle.net and I'll shove the code in for you... ah - you're too quick!

Comment: @Titanium http://jsfiddle.net/LJ4NG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long this is for aesthetics, this should be what you're looking for:

```
.container {
  animation: timer 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes timer {
  0% {  opacity: 0; }
  80% {  opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

Remeber not to use `display:none` with these CSS3 animations or they won't show at all. All I've done is make another CSS3 animation that initially hides the element, and at 80% sets the opacity at 0 (again) so you can start the fade from 80% to 100%.

Another thing to bear in mind is your browser compatibility with this.  Just add to the beginning of each animation and keyframe function (I'm taking the keyframes function as an example):

```
@keyframes example { }
@-moz-keyframes example { } /* Firefox */
@-webkit-keyframes example { } /* Safari and Chrome */
@-o-keyframes example { } /* Opera */
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Quick Question - Why can I only use it for aesthetics?

Comment: This code will not 'finish' once the page has loaded.  This will start when the page has loaded.  You will have to use JavaScript to use this for a certian functionality (such as loading new content into the page using AJAX or the page loading it's objects and content).  Take it as a 'video' at the moment.